# TIdTCPServer accessing custom AContext properties

Tags: delphi, indy

When we assign custom properties to the Context of a connection on TIdTCPServer, how to access this properties (read/write) in a thread-safe manner? Example:

The custom properties:

```
type
  Local_Socket = class(TIdContext)
  public
    Tunnel_Requested: bool;
    Remote_Tunnel: TIdContext;
  end;

type
  Remote_Socket = class(TIdContext)
  public
    Local_Tunnel: TIdContext;
  end;
```

Assigning them:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
      if AContext.Binding.PeerIP = '127.0.0.1' then
      begin
        Local_Socket(AContext).Tunnel_Requested:= false;
        Local_Socket(AContext).Remote_Tunnel:= Nil;
      end
      else
      begin
        AssignRemoteTunnel(AContext);
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.AssignRemoteTunnel(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  iContext: integer;
  List: TIdContextList;
  Assigned: bool;
begin
  Assigned:= false;
  List:= IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for iContext:= 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (TIdContext(List[iContext]).Binding.PeerIP = '127.0.0.1') and
        (Local_Socket(List[iContext]).Remote_Tunnel = Nil) then
      begin
        Local_Socket(List[iContext]).Remote_Tunnel:= AContext;
        Remote_Socket(AContext).Local_Tunnel:= TIdContext(List[iContext]);
        Assigned:= true;
      end;
    end;
    if Assigned = false then
      AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

What I try to achieve with this code is, if a connection is local (127.0.0.1), I need to redirect it to a remote connection, that will be requested on the code below. Once the remote connection arrives on server, I AssignRemoteTunnel, correlating the local_socket.remote_tunnel property with the remote connection, and the remote_socket.local_tunnel with the local connection, this way I can transparently communicate between the tunnel:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
begin
      if AContext.Binding.PeerIP = '127.0.0.1' then
      begin
          if Local_Socket(AContext).Tunnel_Requested = false then
          begin
            TunnelSocket.Connection.IOHandler.Write(REQ_TUNNEL);
            Local_Socket(AContext).Tunnel_Requested:= true;
          end;
          if (Local_Socket(AContext).Remote_Tunnel <> Nil) and
            (Local_Socket(AContext).Remote_Tunnel.Connection.Connected) then
          begin
            AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(500);
            if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
            begin
              AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(Buffer);
              Local_Socket(AContext).Remote_Tunnel.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Buffer);
            end;
end;
```

Here I'm watching if I assigned a remote_tunnel property to send the buffer over this remote_tunnel... But while I read this property, maybe I'm writting it on the AssignRemoteTunnel procedure. Is this OK?

Comment: thread safety can be achieved by TMonitor.Lock - https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/thread-synchronization-with-guarded-blocks-in-delphi/ but the real issue seems to be TYPE SAFETY. ` Local_Socket(AContext).Tunnel_Requested ` - is it correct ? I think you should either check `IF  AContext  IS Local_Socket THEN BEGIN ...` or better here do `WITH AContext AS Local_Socket DO BEGIN Tunnel_Requested:= false; Remote_Tunnel:= Nil; END;`

Comment: Thanks for the info. About TMonitor.Lock, I was thinking in using TIdThreadSafe class, this way I keep everything on Indy classes.

Comment: I am not versed in Indy... but why do you think your context would be not standard Indy classes but your own extended ones ?

Comment: Not sure if I got your last question, but I just want to keep a pattern using Indy classes, as I'm already using IdTCPServer / IdTCPClient. I will look for TMonitor and try to understand it better.

Comment: the `Local_Socket` is not Indy class, why do you use it ? Why do you think your `Local_Socket(AContext).Tunnel_Requested := ...` line is correct and would not give you Access Violation ? To me it looks as poorly substantiated as `Local_Socket(Button1).Tunnel_Requested := ...` or `Local_Socket(i).Tunnel_Requested := ...` would be

Comment: But I'm trying to make sure that Local_Socket will be assigned once the connection arrives, so I will always have this class associated with the context.

Comment: yeah, exactly, "But I'm *trying* to make sure". But what you try might work always or might not. So your event handlers should first check if the object really belongs to the extended class u expect before using it. So - i think you better use `WITH-AS` or `IF-IS` like I outlined in 1st comment

Comment: Yep, I will do that for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just type-cast a `TIdContext` pointer to another class type unless the object being pointed at is actually that class type to begin with.  `TIdTCPServer` has a `ContextClass` property to specify the class type for `TIdContext` objects, but you can only assign one class type to it, so you can't have some clients who are using `Local_Socket` and some clients who are using `Remote_Socket` instead.  You need to merge them into one class.

Make sure you use the `TIdTCPServer.OnDisconnect` event to unassociate your Context objects from each other.

Also, make sure any code that uses the `Tunnel` pointers is thread-safe, since `TIdTCPServer` is multi-threaded and a TCP connection can drop out at any time while other threads are still accessing it.  So, that likely means adding a `TCriticalSection` to each `TMyContext`, or using `TMonitor`, to lock access every time you want to read/write something over a `Tunnel`.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext) // <-- must derive from TIdServerContext, not TIdContext itself
  public
    IsLocal: Boolean;
    Tunnel: TIdContext;
    WaitingForTunnel: Boolean;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.ContextClass := TMyContext; // <-- must be done BEFORE the server is activated!
  IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Ctx: TMyContext;
  PeerIP: string;
  LocalIPs: TIdStackLocalAddressList;
begin
  Ctx := TMyContext(AContext);

  // Note: unless your server is listening specifically on 127.0.0.1 only,
  // you should match the connected PeerIP to all IPs reported by
  // GStack.GetLocalAddressList(), not just 127.0.0.1, since the client
  // could be connecting from any local adapter/interface...
  //
  PeerIP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
  Ctx.IsLocal := (PeerIP = '127.0.0.1') or (PeerIP = '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1') or (PeerIP = '::1');
  if not Ctx.IsLocal then
  begin
    LocalIPs := TIdStackLocalAddressList.Create;
    try
      GStack.GetLocalAddressList(LocalIPs);
      Ctx.IsLocal := (LocalIPs.IndexOfIP(PeerIP) <> -1);
    finally
      LocalIPs.Free;
    end;
  end;
  if Ctx.IsLocal then
  begin
    Ctx.WaitingForTunnel := True;

    // NOTE: unless REQ_TUNNEL is a single Byte, you need to serialize
    // access to TunnelSocket.Connection.IOHandler.Write() so that multiple
    // requests cannot overlap on top of each other, corrupting the
    // communications on that connection!
    //
    TMonitor.Enter(TunnelSocket);
    try
      TunnelSocket.Connection.IOHandler.Write(REQ_TUNNEL);
    finally
      TMonitor.Leave(TunnelSocket);
    end;
  end
  else
    AssignRemoteTunnel(AContext);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  i: integer;
  List: TIdContextList;
  Ctx: TIdContext;
begin
  List := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Ctx := TIdContext(List[i]);
      if Ctx <> AContext then
      begin
        TMonitor.Enter(Ctx);
        try
          if Ctx.Tunnel = AContext then
          begin
            Ctx.Tunnel := nil;
            Exit;
          end;
        finally
          TMonitor.Leave(Ctx);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.AssignRemoteTunnel(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  i: integer;
  List: TIdContextList;
  Ctx: TIdContext;
begin
  Assigned := False;
  List := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Ctx := TIdContext(List[i]);
      if (Ctx <> AContext) and Ctx.IsLocal and Ctx.WaitingForTunnel then
      begin
        TMonitor.Enter(Ctx);
        try
          Ctx.Tunnel := AContext;
          Ctx.WaitingForTunnel := False;
        finally
          TMonitor.Leave(Ctx);
        end;
        TMonitor.Enter(AContext);
        try
          TMyContext(AContext).Tunnel := Ctx;
        finally
          TMonitor.Leave(AContext);
        end;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Ctx: TMyContext;
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
begin
  Ctx := TMyContext(AContext);
  if Ctx.Tunnel = nil then
  begin
    if Ctx.IsLocal and Ctx.WaitingForTunnel then
      IndySleep(50)
    else
      AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    Exit;
  end;
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(500);
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(Buffer);
  TMonitor.Enter(Ctx);
  try
    if Ctx.Tunnel <> nil then
      Ctx.Tunnel.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Buffer);
  finally
    TMonitor.Leave(Ctx);
  end;
end;
```