# Indy 10 TcpServer create new threads

Tags: multithreading, connection, indy10, tcpserver

On https://stackoverrun.com/de/q/11468851 there is a good example from Remy Lebeau for using foreign TIdContext in a TIdTCPServer.OnExecute procedure. But this only works until Indy 9. With Indy 10 a new Thread mechanism was introduced. TIdContext no longer is directly connected to a connection. How is it now possible to create a new thread for example to disconnect the connection or write some data to the client?

Answer (score 1):

> On https://stackoverrun.com/de/q/11468851 there is a good example from Remy Lebeau for using foreign TIdContext in a TIdTCPServer.OnExecute procedure.

That post is just a mirror of this question here on StackOverflow:

[TIdTCPServer accessing custom AContext properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677733/)

> But this only works until Indy 9.

Not true.  That example was written for Indy 10.

> With Indy 10 a new Thread mechanism was introduced. TIdContext no longer is directly connected to a connection.

`TIdContext` was actually introduced in Indy 10, to separate user data from threads.  The idea being that a per-client context could be allowed to move between multiple threads/fibers <sup>1</sup>.  However, `TIdContext` does have a `Yarn` property, which can be type-casted to `TIdYarnOfThread` to access the underlying `TIdThreadWithTask` that the `TIdContext` is currently running in.

<sup>1: but in reality, that was never implemented for threads, and fiber support didn't work out so it was abandoned.</sup>

Indy 9 and earlier used `TIdPeerThread` to track user data directly in threads.  `TIdPeerThread` doesn't exist in Indy 10, it was replaced with `TIdThreadWithTask` and `TIdContext` (which is derived from `TIdTask`).

> How is it now possible to create a new thread for example to disconnect the connection or write some data to the client?

If you want to create a custom *thread* class for `TIdTCPServer` in Indy 10, rather than (or maybe in addition to) a custom *context* class, then you can do the following:

- derive a custom class from `TIdThreadWithTask` and `override` its `virtual` methods as needed.
- explicitly assign a `TIdSchedulerOfThread...` component (`TIdSchedulerOfThreadDefault` or `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool`) to the `TIdTCPServer.Scheduler` property.  If you don't do this, `TIdTCPServer` will create an internal `TIdSchedulerOfThreadDefault` for itself, and you won't have an opportunity to tell it what kind of thread class to use.
- assign your thread class type to the Scheduler's `ThreadClass` property.

This is equivalent to deriving from `TIdPeerThread` and setting `TIdTCPServer.ThreadClass` in Indy 9.